# Unwrapping UITableView cell text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm trying to get the text on a table view cell and then get the index of it in an array.

This is the code I'm using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let indexOfCellString = event.index(of: cell.textLabel!.text)
}
```

But I get the following errors:

1. value of optional type string? not unwrapped
2. invalid character in source file

What is going on here? What else do I need to unwrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no need to cast `dequeueReusableCell` to `UITableViewCell` since that is its return type.
2. `cell.textLabel` is optional. And then the `text` property of `UILabel` is optional.

Properly deal with optionals:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let text = cell.textLabel?.text {
        let indexOfCellString = event.index(text)
        // do stuff with indexOfCellString
    }

    return cell
}
```